# How to set value of multiple variable in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to set value of multiple variable in SQL Server 2008. Like

```
Set @a = 10, @b = 'James'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides using `SELECT @a = 10, @b = 'James'`, if you just want to set the values the first time they are declared, you can set the values of multiple variables when declaring them, as shown below:

```
DECLARE  @a  INT = 10, @b VARCHAR(10)  = 'James' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `SELECT` instead of `SET`:

```
SELECT @a = 10, @b = 'James';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @a = 10, @b = 'James'
```

This should work, if the variables are properly declared.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this,

```
Declare @a Int,@b Varchar(10)
select @a=10,@b='James'
```

Answer (score -1):

As follows:

```
SET @a=10
SET @b='James'
```